# Plot lines generated by lines function not displayed on Shiny plot output

Tags: r, plot, shiny

I have a function that makes a call to plot followed by lines then legend. The output is then displayed on a Shiny page.
The problem is that while the plot and legend both show, the lines do not.

This is for Shiny for R.

```
# helper function
myFunction <- function() {
  # plot shows fine
  plot(x=20,
       y=0.4,
       ylab="probability",
       ylim=c(0,1),
       xlab="X axis",
       type="l",
       lty="solid",
       col="blue")

  # lines do not show
  lines(20, 0.5,lty="dashed", col="red")

  # legend shows fine
  legend("topright",
         inset=0.02,
         legend=c("vote yes", "vote no"),
         lty=c("solid","dashed"),
         col=c("blue","red"))
}

# server code
  observe({
    output$plot <- renderPlot({
      myFunction()
    })
  })
```

I get a plot with the legend. But the lines do not show up. I've tried it outside Shiny and everything displayed fine.

Comment: What does a line with only one look like? Both `plot(..., type="l")` and `lines(...)` have a foregone assumption that there are at least two ends.

Comment: (To be clear ... I do *not* get anything other than axes and legend.)

Comment: I do, however, if I change `plot` and append `lines` to use `type="b"`. But you probably don't want the points. (Back to thought one: two points define a line (segment), your coordinates only have one.)